# Quick question about Ubuntu on External HDD

Tags: boot, external-hdd

I'm new to Ubuntu and after some Google search, I manage to install Ubuntu on my external drive (4 partitions) with the following setup:
sdb1: Ubuntu and Grub (60gb)
sdb2: swap (7GB)
sdb3&4: file storages

So far it is working well for me, I can boot it on my laptop when I want to.
Question is, will it be able to boot on any other laptops or pcs. If it is, is there any problem that I should be aware of?

I'm sorry if there is already a similar topic, I could not find anything.

Comment: Can I ask you where did you learn to make 2 partitions (sdb 3&4) for your files, I keep seeing this, what is the point of it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer : Yes if they have boot from USB

Longer answer : Only if they meet the required specs for Ubuntu (and any modifications you made), also I tried this once and had various bugs on different hardware due to things like drivers, graphics could be a issue I don't know how a AMD GPU would react to finding the Nvidia driver.

But for me at least it mostly worked very well for the most part.

Comment: Thank you, I was afraid about testing this on other computers in case things go wrong.

Comment: Bear in mind, things can go wrong, I SAID FOR ME IT WAS MOSTLY FINE, please back up all data and be careful, just to be safe

Comment: I do keep my important data separate in another drive. But aside from that, will keeping backup on another partition of the Ubuntu external drive be safe enough?

Comment: Your data partitions dev sdb 3&4 should be fine, if you use them but the / (ubuntu system) partition which includes your /home folder is that has potential to go wrong, please accept the answer with the tick if this is satisfying to you.